# VBA WildCard in Excel List Objects

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I have a list object loaded and I'm trying to filter it with the code below.
If I use a fixed SQL statement below the code works as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM [All Contracts] WHERE [Asset_Number] = "Q123456"
```

However trying to bring in any form of wildcard to the search string results in a 1004 error.
[image: Dreaded 1004 Error]

Here is the current sub in question:

```
Public Sub QueryData( _
    ByVal form As Variant _
    )
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = form.Worksheet
    
    Dim searchTxt As String
    Let searchTxt = form.textBox_FirstAssetNumber.value
    
    ' Build the SQL Statment
    Dim SQL As String
    If searchTxt = vbNullString Then
        Let SQL = "Array(SELECT * FROM [All_Contracts])"
    Else
        Let SQL = "SELECT * FROM [All Contracts] WHERE (((Asset_Number) Like %" & [searchTxt] & "%));"
    End If
    
    #If Testing = 1 Then
        Debug.Print "SQL Satatment is: " & SQL
    #End If
    
    With ws.ListObjects.item(1).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried replacing 'Like' with Where, also '*' with '%' added brackets, removed brackets all seem to result in a 104 error.

The code and SQL work if I do not use the wildcard in the query.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The wildcards and the text you are searching for should be within quotes.

```vb
SQL = "SELECT * FROM [All Contracts] WHERE Asset_Number Like '%" & searchTxt & "%';"
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work either.

 Let SQL = "SELECT * FROM [All Contracts] WHERE Asset_Number Like '%" & searchTxt & "%';"

Comment: However, Changing the 'Like' to '=' does not cause a 1004 error. But still no result for the query is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL = "Select * FROM [All Contracts$] WHERE [Asset_Number] LIKE '%" & searchTxt & "%'"
```

"All Contracts" is a Sheet tab?

Comment: "All Contracts" is a PowerQuery